# Remove newlines in Redis

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I dump all data to a text file using `redis-dump > output.txt` command. 
Output file contains SET commands which consists of multiple lines.

```
SET     3ds:request:021333976bab4102a6d119293a1d0717 '{
  "offer" : {
    "id" : 0,
    "secureId" : "796a623e-77f1-427b-86ac-6d1d0fede212"
  },
}'
```

I import output.txt into another redis server using `cat output.txt | redis-cli` command. I get following error messages:

`(error) ERR unknown command 'offer'`

I guess this is happening because of the newline characters inside the data.

How can I delete these newline characters? Or is there a better approach to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you suggest to just copy the data file?

Comment: Do you have an objection to that? You're fundamentally doing a backup and restore here, and Redis recommends the RDB files for backing up. https://redis.io/topics/persistence